# How defining private static final field in multiple ways matter

Tags: java

What is the difference between

```
 private static final String JDBC_URL = getURL();
```

and then defining the `getURL()` like:

```
private static String getURL() {
        return "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    }
```

with the following code:

```
private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
```

I found that writing `mock` test was easier with the above one. I might be wrong. Just wanted to know if both ways are same. Thanks.

Comment: I see no difference.

Comment: If you are using `getURL()` in other parts of your program, you might as well use it when initializing `JDBC_URL` for consistency. But there probably is no real difference.

Comment: Seems like second approach is more readable

Comment: @JakubBibro yes it is but what if he adds a URL setter and needs to get the value of URL later? So first if the getter is modified would be more modular.

Comment: @jgr208 that's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second way is a compile-time constant, so elsewhere in your code when you refer to the value, it won't actually refer to the field - it will just have the value baked in.

Unless you start messing with the field via reflection or something similarly nasty you shouldn't notice any semantic differences, but that *will* be a difference in the bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference at all in what the value of the variable is only difference is how you are setting the variable and how it is interpreted at run time.

With the first one you are setting the variable by calling a function and using that functions return value so the variable is not set until after the program is ran.

In the second call you are just setting right away by using an assignment and not calling a function and assigning the return value of that function to the variable so that variable is also set when the program is compiled and not at run time.

Comment: There is quite an important difference, the second is a constant expression.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that is true. so it does save a little time at run time, but in terms of going out of scope unless he's on an embedded system or one with big constrains shouldn't have a performance impact

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have said, in the first case the variable is assigned at run-time whereas in the second is mostly inlined at compile-time.  This can matter even without using reflection.

Two specific cases, which provide contradictory advice:

## Case 1: Circular References

Under some rare circumstances involving circular class references, it is **better to initialise with a literal string**, because a constant initialised with an expression may not be initialised as soon as you need, resulting in surprising `null`s.

E.g. the output of the code below is

```
1null
2foo
```

pkg/tmp.java:

```
package pkg;
class tmp {
  static { tmp2.go(1); }
  public static final String FOO = foo();
  static { tmp2.go(2); }
  private static String foo() { return "foo"; }
  public static void main(String[] args) { }
}
```

pkg/tmp2.java:

```
package pkg;
class tmp2 {
  public static void go(int n) {
    System.out.println(n + tmp.FOO);
  }
}
```

## Case 2: Separate Compilation

If you compile `Class1` which defines a constant, then separately compile `Class2` which uses the constant, and the constant in `Class1` might be updated in future versions of the code, it is **better to initialise via a method call** to prevent the compiler from inlining the value.  If the constant were initialised from a literal string, then `Class2` would have had the old constant value put into it at compile time and would not reference the field in `Class1` at runtime at all.

A common case of this would be if the constant in question is inside a library, and you compile a project against v1.0 of a library, but deploy it with v2.0 of the library.  Worse, if in v2.0 of the library the constant is initialised from an expression, you can't spot the problem from looking at v2.0 of the library.

## Other notes

- The concatenation of two string literals with `+` will be evaluated at compile time, be considered a string literal, and be inlined as such.
- There is a program called `javap` that comes with the JDK that can extract and disassemble the the bytecode out of classes, which is useful for tracking down problems like this.  Your IDE may provide similar disassembly/decompilation functionality.